# Connection between GPGGA HDOP and GPGST deviations

Tags: gps, nmea

I would like some clarification regarding HDOP in the GPGGA message (Field 9) and standard deviation of latitude/longitude error in GPGST message (Fields 7 and 8). Are the values presented in the GPGST message same as the ones used for HDOP calculation? As to my current understanding HDOP is based on variances of x and y positions. HDOP = sqrt(sigma_x^2 + sigma_y^2). So, if I have the standard deviations from GPGST message, is it correct to use these for HDOP calculation?

Here is an example. I highlighted HDOP and std.dev values.

$GPGGA,105318.70,5524.6923851,N,01840.7127875,E,5,12,**0.95**,14.553,M,18.557,M,4.7,0000*48
$GPGST,105318.70,63,0.68,0.22,166,**0.26**,**0.11**,0.25*57

It seems the values 0.26 (sigma_lat) and 0.11 (sigma_lon) do not give an HDOP of 0.95. Am I missing something here or misunderstood something?

https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/Logs/GPGGA.htm 
https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/Logs/GPGST.htm

Answer (score 0):

The values in GGA and GST are almost unrelated.

DOP is determined purely by the geometry of the GNSS satellites - if you are tracking lots of satellites and they are spread around the sky you will have a low (good) DOP value.  If you are in a location where the view of the sky is blocked in some directions, the geometry is worse so DOP values will increase.

The accuracy estimate values in GST are determined by the GNSS receiver based on the signals received and are the GNSS receiver's estimate of Lat, Long, Alt errors, which will depend on DOP and number of satellites and how well the signals from the various satellites match each other, etc.

The GST accuracy estimates are related to the DOP to some degree - in general, higher DOP values will give worse accuracy - but the accuracy estimates also depend on the GNSS conditions.  For example, walking under trees may not cause the DOP to change much because the GNSS still tracks the same satellites, but the accuracy estimates should get worse because the GNSS signals get weaker and multipath increases.

In an open field with no GNSS interference (and without SBAS or NTRIP corrections, etc.) I'd expect the GNSS in a mobile phone and a Survey-grade GNSS receiver to give very similar DOP values (PDOP of about 0.7), since they only look at the geometry of satellites which are tracked, but accuracy estimates ***should*** be much lower for the survey grade GNSS receiver since it would have a better antenna as well as better hardware.  I say "should" because mobile phone manufacturers are quite often optimistic in their estimates while reputable Survey GNSS manufacturers are usually more realistic.